# Deserializing from JSON into PHP, with casting?

Tags: php, json, serialization

Suppose I have a User class with 'name' and 'password' properties, and a 'save' method. When serializing an object of this class to JSON via json_encode, the method is properly skipped and I end up with something like {'name': 'testName', 'password': 'testPassword'}.

However, when deserializing via json_decode, I end up with a StdClass object instead of a User object, which makes sense but this means the object lacks the 'save' method. Is there any way to cast the resultant object as a User, or to provide some hint to json_decode as to what type of object I'm expecting?

Answer (score 26):

Old question, but maybe someone will find this useful.
I've created an abstract class with static functions that you can inherit on your object in order to deserialize any JSON into the inheriting class instance.

```
abstract class JsonDeserializer
{
    /**
     * @param string|array $json
     * @return $this
     */
    public static function Deserialize($json)
    {
        $className = get_called_class();
        $classInstance = new $className();
        if (is_string($json))
            $json = json_decode($json);

        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            if (!property_exists($classInstance, $key)) continue;

            $classInstance->{$key} = $value;
        }

        return $classInstance;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $json
     * @return $this[]
     */
    public static function DeserializeArray($json)
    {
        $json = json_decode($json);
        $items = [];
        foreach ($json as $item)
            $items[] = self::Deserialize($item);
        return $items;
    }
}
```

You use it by inheriting it on a class which has the values that your JSON will have:

```
class MyObject extends JsonDeserializer
{
    /** @var string */
    public $property1;

    /** @var string */
    public $property2;

    /** @var string */
    public $property3;

    /** @var array */
    public $array1;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$objectInstance = new MyObject();
$objectInstance->property1 = 'Value 1';
$objectInstance->property2 = 'Value 2';
$objectInstance->property3 = 'Value 3';
$objectInstance->array1 = ['Key 1' => 'Value 1', 'Key 2' => 'Value 2'];

$jsonSerialized = json_encode($objectInstance);

$deserializedInstance = MyObject::Deserialize($jsonSerialized);
```

You can use the `::DeserializeArray` method if your JSON contains an array of your target object.

[Here](http://ideone.com/1xMSev)'s a runnable sample.

Comment: Excellent. I took part of your Deserialize() method and used it in my constructor which receives the JSON as a parameter. This way I can create new class, passing it in the JSON and the result is an instance of my class with the data populated in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best way to handle this would be via the constructor, either directly or via a factory:

```
class User
{
   public $username;
   public $nestedObj; //another class that has a constructor for handling json
   ...

   // This could be make private if the factories below are used exclusively
   // and then make more sane constructors like:
   //     __construct($username, $password)
   public function __construct($mixed)
   {
       if (is_object($mixed)) {
           if (isset($mixed->username))
               $this->username = $mixed->username;
           if (isset($mixed->nestedObj) && is_object($mixed->nestedObj))
               $this->nestedObj = new NestedObject($mixed->nestedObj);
           ...
       } else if (is_array($mixed)) {
           if (isset($mixed['username']))
               $this->username = $mixed['username'];
           if (isset($mixed['nestedObj']) && is_array($mixed['nestedObj']))
               $this->nestedObj = new NestedObj($mixed['nestedObj']);
           ...
       }
   }
   ...

   public static fromJSON_by_obj($json)
   {
       return new self(json_decode($json));
   }

   public static fromJSON_by_ary($json)
   {
       return new self(json_decode($json, TRUE)); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly.  JSON has no way of encoding what kind of object the original was.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: No (not that I know of*)

Long answer: json_encode will only serialize public variables.  As you can see per the [JSON spec](http://json.org/), there is no "function" datatype. These are both reasons why your methods aren't serialized into your JSON object.

Ryan Graham is right - the only way to re-create these objects as non-stdClass instances is to re-create them post-deserialization.

Example

```
<?php

class Person
{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;

    public function __construct( $firstName, $lastName )
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public static function createFromJson( $jsonString )
    {
        $object = json_decode( $jsonString );
        return new self( $object->firstName, $object->lastName );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
    }
}

$p = new Person( 'Peter', 'Bailey' );
$jsonPerson = json_encode( $p );

$reconstructedPerson = Person::createFromJson( $jsonPerson );

echo $reconstructedPerson->getName();
```

Alternatively, unless you really need the data as JSON, you can just use [normal serialization](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop.serialization.php) and leverage the [__sleep() and __wakeup() hooks](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop.magic-functions.php) to achieve additional customization.

`*` In [a previous question of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401908/php-tostring-and-jsonencode-not-playing-well-together) it was suggested that you could implement some of the SPL interfaces to customize the input/output of json_encode() but my tests revealed those to be wild goose chases.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a FactoryClass of some sort:

```
function create(array $data)  
{
    $user = new User();
    foreach($data as $k => $v) {
        $user->$k = $v;
    }
    return $user;
}
```

It's not like the solution you wanted, but it gets your job done.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this class I wrote:

https://github.com/mindplay-dk/jsonfreeze/blob/master/mindplay/jsonfreeze/JsonSerializer.php

It reserves a JSON object-property named '#type' to store the class-name, and it has some limitations that are described here:

[Serialize/unserialize PHP object-graph to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489876)

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but another option is to use symfony serializer to deserialize xml, json, whatever to Object.

here is documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object

Comment: The only fully reusable solution of all answers, and very easy to apply. Should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that JSON doesn't support the serialization of functions, which is perfectly acceptable, and even desired. My classes are currently used as value objects in communicating with JavaScript, and functions would hold no meaning (and the regular serialization functions aren't usable).

However, as the functionality pertaining to these classes increases, encapsulating their utility functions (such as a User's save() in this case) inside the actual class makes sense to me. This does mean they're no longer strictly value objects though, and that's where I run into my aforementioned problem.

An idea I had would have the class name specified inside the JSON string, and would probably end up like this:

```
$string = '{"name": "testUser", "password": "testPassword", "class": "User"}';
$object = json_decode ($string);
$user = ($user->class) $object;
```

And the reverse would be setting the class property during/after json_encode. I know, a bit convoluted, but I'm just trying to keep related code together. I'll probably end up taking my utility functions out of the classes again; the modified constructor approach seems a bit opaque and runs into trouble with nested objects.

I do appreciate this and any future feedback, however.

Comment: Take a look at the J2EE world where you would create a separate class for encapsulating the operations you would be performing on the data-only object. In this case, maybe User and UserHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `hydration` pattern can be of help.

Basically you instantiate an new empty object (`new User()`) and then you fill in the properties with values from the `StdClass` object. For example you could have a `hydrate` method in `User`.

If possible in your case, you can make the `User` `constructor` accept an optional parameter of type `StdClass` and take the values at instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, new answer.

What about creating your own interface to match [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php)? ;)

```php
/**
 * Interface JsonUnseriablizable
 */
interface JsonUnseriablizable {
    /**
     * @param array $json
     */
    public function jsonUnserialize(array $json);
}
```

example:

```php
/**
 * Class Person
 */
class Person implements JsonUnseriablizable {

    public $name;
    public $dateOfBirth;

    /**
     * @param string $json
     */
    public function jsonUnserialize(array $json)
    {
        $this->name = $json['name'] ?? $this->name;
        $this->dateOfBirth = $json['date_of_birth'] ?? $this->dateOfBirth;
    }
}

$json = '{"name":"Bob","date_of_birth":"1970-01-01"}';

$person = new Person();
if($person instanceof JsonUnseriablizable){
    $person->jsonUnserialize(json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
}

var_dump($person->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, no, there's no was to do this with json_encode/json_decode.  JSON was designed and specified to be a format for encoding information, and not for serializing objects.  The PHP function don't go beyond that.

If you're interested in recreating objects from JSON, one possible solution is a static method on all the objects in your hierarchy that accepts a stdClass/string and populates variables that looks something like this

```
//semi pseudo code, not tested
static public function createFromJson($json){
    //if you pass in a string, decode it to an object
    $json = is_string($json) ? json_decode($json) : $json;

    foreach($json as $key=>$value){
        $object = new self();
        if(is_object($value)){
            $object->{$key} = parent::createFromJson($json);
        }
        else{
            $object->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    return $object;
}
```

I didn't test that, but I hope it gets the idea across. Ideally, all your objects should extend from some base object (usually named "class Object") so you can add this code in one place only.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of using both static (i.e. you know the class type in code) and dynamic (i.e. you only know the class type at runtime) to deserialize JSON back into a PHP object:

### Code

```
<?php

class Car
{
    private $brand;
    private $model;
    private $year;

    public function __construct($brand, $model, $year)
    {
        $this->brand = $brand;
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->year = $year;
    }

    public function toJson()
    {
        $arr = array(
            'brand' => $this->brand,
            'model' => $this->model,
            'year' => $this->year,
        );

        return json_encode($arr);
    }

    public static function fromJson($json)
    {
        $arr = json_decode($json, true);

        return new self(
            $arr['brand'],
            $arr['model'],
            $arr['year']
        );
    }
}

// original object
echo 'car1: ';
$car1 = new Car('Hyundai', 'Tucson', 2010);
var_dump($car1);

// serialize
echo 'car1class: ';
$car1class = get_class($car1); // need the class name for the dynamic case below. this would need to be bundled with the JSON to know what kind of class to recreate.
var_dump($car1class);

echo 'car1json: ';
$car1Json = $car1->toJson();
var_dump($car1Json);

// static recreation with direct invocation. can only do this if you know the class name in code.
echo 'car2: ';
$car2 = Car::fromJson($car1Json);
var_dump($car2);

// dynamic recreation with reflection. can do this when you only know the class name at runtime as a string.
echo 'car3: ';
$car3 = (new ReflectionMethod($car1class, 'fromJson'))->invoke(null, $car1Json);
var_dump($car3);
```

### Output

```
car1: object(Car)#1 (3) {
  ["brand":"Car":private]=>
  string(7) "Hyundai"
  ["model":"Car":private]=>
  string(6) "Tucson"
  ["year":"Car":private]=>
  int(2010)
}
car1class: string(3) "Car"
car1json: string(48) "{"brand":"Hyundai","model":"Tucson","year":2010}"
car2: object(Car)#2 (3) {
  ["brand":"Car":private]=>
  string(7) "Hyundai"
  ["model":"Car":private]=>
  string(6) "Tucson"
  ["year":"Car":private]=>
  int(2010)
}
car3: object(Car)#4 (3) {
  ["brand":"Car":private]=>
  string(7) "Hyundai"
  ["model":"Car":private]=>
  string(6) "Tucson"
  ["year":"Car":private]=>
  int(2010)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 8.1 allows to do it easily.
Suppose you have a class A:

```
Class A {
    public function __construct(
        public string $firstName,
        public int $age) {
    }
}
```

The easiest way to import from JSON:

```
$a = new A(...json_decode('{"firstName": "John", "age": 73}', true));
```

And that's all, folks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the JMS (de)serializer: https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer . It can be loaded using Composer.

> This library allows you to (de-)serialize data of any complexity.
> Currently, it supports XML and JSON.
>
> It also provides you with a rich tool-set to adapt the output to your
> specific needs.
>
> Built-in features include:
>
> - (De-)serialize data of any complexity; circular references and    complex exclusion strategies are handled gracefully.
> - Supports many built-in PHP types (such as dates, intervals)
> - Integrates with Doctrine ORM, et. al.
> - Supports versioning, e.g. for APIs
> - Configurable via XML, YAML, or Annotations