# JSON string looping issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I am having a json string

```
[{"part_id":"66","part_name":"Palet crate","part_image":"crate-box.gif","0":{"language_data_content":"Length [mm]","pgd_value":"1000"},"1":{"language_data_content":"Width [mm]","pgd_value":"800"},"2":{"language_data_content":"Height [mm]","pgd_value":"800"},"3":{"language_data_content":"Thickness [mm]","pgd_value":"20"}}]
```

This is a part of a Ajax response from my action in a controller

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($partlist);$i++){              
            $jsondata[$i]['part_id'] = $partlist[$i]['part_id'];
            $jsondata[$i]['part_name'] = $partlist[$i]['part_name'];
            $jsondata[$i]['part_image'] = $partlist[$i]['part_image'];
            $gdata = $pgdata->getPropertyDimensions($partlist[$i]['part_id'],1);
            if(count($gdata) > 0){
                $j = 0;
                foreach($gdata as $g){
                    $jsondata[$i][$j]['language_data_content'] = $g->language_data_content;
                    $jsondata[$i][$j]['pgd_value'] = $g->pgd_value;
                    $j++;
                }
            }           
        } 
       echo json_encode($jsondata);exit;
```

For one part id there can be multiple **pgd_value** In this json array there is only one part id and four **pgd_value**..on my ajax success function in looping this json as

```
success:function(msg){
str = '';
  if(msg.length > 0){
                for(j=0;j<msg.length;j++){
   str +='<span>'+msg[j]['part_id']+'</span>';
   // here i want to loop those four **pgd_value** values from json is it possible ?

}
}

}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.map` to select the `pgd_values`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/6LLVe/1/

```
var str = '';
if (msg.length > 0) {
    for (j = 0; j < msg.length; j++) {
        var pgdValues = $.map(msg[j], function(item) {
            if (item['pgd_value']) return item['pgd_value'];
        });
        str += '<span> Part ID ' + msg[j]['part_id'] + ' pgd_values ' + pgdValues.join(', ') + '</span>';
        // OP: here i want to loop those four **pgd_value** values from json is it possible ?
        // ME: yep. all the IDs are now accessible from `pgdValues`


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var msg = [{
    "part_id": "66",
    "part_name": "Palet crate",
    "part_image": "crate-box.gif",
    "0": {
        "language_data_content": "Length [mm]",
        "pgd_value": "1000"
    },
    "1": {
        "language_data_content": "Width [mm]",
        "pgd_value": "800"
    },
    "2": {
        "language_data_content": "Height [mm]",
        "pgd_value": "800"
    },
    "3": {
        "language_data_content": "Thickness [mm]",
        "pgd_value": "20"
    }}];
    var data = msg[0]; // extract the whole object from array
    // loop over object
    for (var key in data) {
        // checking for key which contain pgd_value
        // as you mentioned about only 4 pgd_values 
        // so here is the checking for just 4 index
        if (key == '0' || key == '1' || key == '2' || key == '3') {
            // here I used square bracket notation to 
            // retrieve data from object
            alert(data[key].pgd_value);
        }
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/215/)**

Answer (score 1):

You really should look into just deserializing the JSON into an actual object. It's a lot easier to work with and it makes your code much more readable.

See here: [Deserializing from JSON into PHP, with casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658469/deserializing-from-json-into-php-with-casting)

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$.each(msg,function(index,item){

    alert("Part_ID : "+item.part_id);
    alert(item[0].pgd_value)
    alert(item[1].pgd_value)
    alert(item[2].pgd_value)
    alert(item[3].pgd_value)

})
```

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/Mc2du/29/

But if possible, try to change your JSON to send some string expression instead of 0/1. So that reading it is easy as well as robust). reading on an index is not safe as adding new content to the JSON structure would break the reading code.

Assuming you relace the 0/1 approach with string expressions like this (replaced 0 with Item0). You can read it like this

```
 $.each(msg,function(index,item){
    alert("Part_ID : "+item.part_id);
    alert(item.Item1.pgd_value)
    alert(item.Item2.pgd_value)
    alert(item.Item3.pgd_value)
 })
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Mc2du/28/