# Deserialize a class within a class from a JSON query in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have two classes like this (as it is in C#)

```
public class inside
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
}

public class outside
{
    public inside[] items {get;set;}
}
```

I then do a query to the server and deserialize the JSON values that come back into the outside class.

I've been asked if I can port this over to PHP and I've come up with

```
class inside
{
    public $name;
    public $id;
    public $value;
}

class outside
{
    public array $item -> inside;
```

with pretty much everything else coming from [Deserializing from JSON into PHP, with casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658469/deserializing-from-json-into-php-with-casting)

for the outside class deserialization.

No real surprise in that it doesn't actually work for me (I stopped doing PHP years ago as it annoyed the hell out of me that PHP was an all or nothing language - if you don't see something, something is wrong)

The stumbler I think is how to I link the inside class to the outside class in the same way as I would in C#?

Comment: PHP doesn't have variable types, nor does it have "generic" arrays.  You can't declare a variable as being an "array of `inside` objects".  You just need to make it an array, and remember that it contains `inside` objects.

Comment: Thanks. In this case would I simply have public array $items => new inside?

Comment: You'd just have `public $items = array()`.  Then you would, when programming, have to remember to only put `inside` objects in there.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to take your returned `JSON` and assign it to the `outside class` as an instance of `inside class` rather than an array?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you pass in an instance of the inside class into the constructor of the outside class and then set that instance to a property of the class:

```
<?php
class inside
{
    public $name;
    public $id;
    public $value;
}

class outside {
   private $inside;

   public function __construct($inside) {
      $this->inside = $inside;
   }
}
?>
```

Hopefully I'm understanding what you're looking for correctly. If not, please let me know. I'm not entirely familiar with C# so I may be misinterpreting what you're trying to accomplish.